# Repeating UILocalNotifications with Gaps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have a notification that needs to repeat daily. It can be turned off by the user for specific days. Is there any easy way to accomplish this scenario using the UILocalNotification framework?

Take an example of a notification that repeats daily starting on March 1st, 2011, and is disabled for March 7th, and March 23rd.

The only solution I've come up with is to create:

- 6 *non-repeating* UILocation
  notifications for March 1st through
  March 6th
- 14 *non-repeating*
  UILocation notifications for March
  8th through March 22nd
- 1 *repeating*
  UILocation notification for March
  24th, repeating daily

This is doable, but requires re-evaulation every time the user changes the deletion dates. Is this the best way to accomplish this type of scenario?

**Edit:** Not to mention the fact that this is approaching (rapidly) the 64-notification limit per app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anyway to establish repeats only for a range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of alarm problems where app has to set notification that repeats irregularly, the best way is to use push notifications. i spent my 2 month wasting on this kind of problem and at last i have to turn to push notifiction. So try push notification asap.:)